# Paypal Null Pointer Exception nvp.get("ACK") Java

Tags: java, servlets, paypal, nullpointerexception, paypal-sandbox

I have been struggling with this seemingly simple integration the whole day. I am really hoping you can help me out.

I need to use PayPal express checkout in my Java webapp. I just need to put a single order and redirect the client to the PayPal page.

Home page works great but when I try to go to check out I get a NullPointerException. NullPointerException is thrown on line 36 of my Checkout class. It is called when I try to get ACK.

I have been trying the whole day to fix this.

Not sure if this is related:
I have made a second project, tapestry5 project and used Rest SDK still I get an exception when I try to invoke setExpressCheckoutResponse.getAck(). I have found that the line in that project that throws an exception is service.setExpressCheckout(setExpressCheckoutReq);

If You have any idea how I could fix this, any tutorial on paypal hello world with servlets or any resource I could check out please help me.

Here is the code I have been trying:

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Integration Wizard</display-name>
    <description></description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Checkout</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Checkout</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Checkout</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/checkout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OrderConfirm</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>OrderConfirm</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OrderConfirm</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/orderconfirm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Cancel</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Cancel</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Cancel</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cancel</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My HelloWorld.java (Home Page)

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

  private String message;

  public void init() throws ServletException {
      message = "Hello World";
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("");

      out.println("<!-- INFO: The post URL \"checkout.java\" is invoked when clicked on \"Pay with PayPal\" button.-->");

      out.println("<form action='/1/checkout' METHOD='POST'>");
      out.println("  <input type='image' name='paypal_submit' id='paypal_submit'  src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Pay with PayPal'/>");
      out.println("</form>");

      out.println("<!-- Add Digital goods in-context experience. Ensure that this script is added before the closing of html body tag -->");

      out.println("<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");

      out.println("<script>");

      out.println("var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(");
      out.println("{");
      out.println("trigger: 'paypal_submit',");
      out.println("expType: 'instant'");
       out.println("//PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.");
      out.println("});");

      out.println("</script>");
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

My Checkout.java (Here the NullPointerException gets thrown at line 36)

```
public class Checkout extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        String paymentAmount = "15.00";

        String returnURL = "localhost:8080/1/HelloWorld";

        String cancelURL = "localhost:8080/1/HelloWorld";

        Map item = new HashMap();
        item.put("name", "item name");
        item.put("amt", paymentAmount);
        item.put("qty", "1");

        PaypalFunctions ppf = new PaypalFunctions();
        HashMap nvp = ppf.setExpressCheckout(paymentAmount, returnURL,
                cancelURL, item);
        String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();

        if (strAck != null && strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {

            // ' Redirect to paypal.com
            String redirectURL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token="
                    + nvp.get("TOKEN").toString();

            response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
        } else {
            // Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the
            // following error information returned by PayPal

            String ErrorCode = nvp.get("L_ERRORCODE0").toString();
            String ErrorShortMsg = nvp.get("L_SHORTMESSAGE0").toString();
            String ErrorLongMsg = nvp.get("L_LONGMESSAGE0").toString();
            String ErrorSeverityCode = nvp.get("L_SEVERITYCODE0").toString();
        }
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

My PaypalFunctions.java

```
public class PaypalFunctions {
    private String gv_APIUserName;
    private String gv_APIPassword;
    private String gv_APISignature;

    private String gv_APIEndpoint;
    private String gv_BNCode;

    private String gv_Version;
    private String gv_nvpHeader;
    private String gv_ProxyServer;
    private String gv_ProxyServerPort;
    private int gv_Proxy;
    private boolean gv_UseProxy;
    private String PAYPAL_URL;

    public PaypalFunctions() {

        gv_APIUserName = "dusan.stanojevic95-facilitator_api1.gmail.com";
        gv_APIPassword = "1405890612";
        gv_APISignature = "AexbutlMdUCD618gs-q4m-DJpUxEAoU-uNDtNNLAb47Su-QoOlNbIjeo";

        boolean bSandbox = true;

        String PAYPAL_DG_URL = null;
        if (bSandbox == true) {
            gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
            PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
            PAYPAL_DG_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=";
        } else {
            gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
            PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
            PAYPAL_DG_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/incontext?token=";
        }

        String HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_SERVER = "";
        String HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PORT = "";
        boolean USE_PROXY = false;

        gv_Version = "84";

        // WinObjHttp Request proxy settings.
        gv_ProxyServer = HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_SERVER;
        gv_ProxyServerPort = HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PORT;
        gv_Proxy = 2; // 'setting for proxy activation
        gv_UseProxy = USE_PROXY;

    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     * SetExpressCheckout: Function to perform the SetExpressCheckout API call
     * 
     * Inputs: paymentAmount: Total value of the purchase currencyCodeType:
     * Currency code value the PayPal API paymentType: 'Sale' for Digital Goods
     * returnURL: the page where buyers return to after they are done with the
     * payment review on PayPal cancelURL: the page where buyers return to when
     * they cancel the payment review on PayPal
     * 
     * Output: Returns a HashMap object containing the response from the server.
     *********************************************************************************/
    public HashMap setExpressCheckout(String paymentAmount, String returnURL,
            String cancelURL, Map item) {

        /*
         * '------------------------------------ ' The currencyCodeType and
         * paymentType ' are set to the selections made on the Integration
         * Assistant '------------------------------------
         */

        String currencyCodeType = "USD";
        String paymentType = "Sale";

        /*
         * Construct the parameter string that describes the PayPal payment the
         * varialbes were set in the web form, and the resulting string is
         * stored in $nvpstr
         */
        String nvpstr = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" + paymentAmount
                + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" + paymentType
                + "&RETURNURL=" + URLEncoder.encode(returnURL) + "&CANCELURL="
                + URLEncoder.encode(cancelURL)
                + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" + currencyCodeType
                + "&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0" + "&NOSHIPPING=1"
                + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=" + item.get("name")
                + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=" + item.get("amt")
                + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=" + item.get("qty")
                + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital";

        /*
         * Make the call to PayPal to get the Express Checkout token If the API
         * call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to
         * authorize payment. If an error occured, show the resulting errors
         */

        HashMap nvp = httpcall("SetExpressCheckout", nvpstr);

        String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();
        if (strAck != null && strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {

            return nvp;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     * GetShippingDetails: Function to perform the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API
     * call
     * 
     * Inputs: None
     * 
     * Output: Returns a HashMap object containing the response from the server.
     *********************************************************************************/
    public HashMap getPaymentDetails(String token) {
        /*
         * Build a second API request to PayPal, using the token as the ID to
         * get the details on the payment authorization
         */

        String nvpstr = "&TOKEN=" + token;

        /*
         * Make the API call and store the results in an array. If the call was
         * a success, show the authorization details, and provide an action to
         * complete the payment. If failed, show the error
         */

        HashMap nvp = httpcall("GetExpressCheckoutDetails", nvpstr);
        String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();

        if (strAck != null
                && (strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success") || strAck
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("SuccessWithWarning"))) {

            return nvp;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     * ConfirmPayment: Function to perform the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call
     * 
     * Inputs: None
     * 
     * Output: Returns a HashMap object containing the response from the server.
     *********************************************************************************/
    public HashMap confirmPayment(String token, String payerID,
            String finalPaymentAmount, String serverName, Map item) {

        /*
         * '------------------------------------ ' The currencyCodeType and
         * paymentType ' are set to the selections made on the Integration
         * Assistant '------------------------------------
         */
        String currencyCodeType = "USD";
        String paymentType = "Sale";

        /*
         * '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         * '---- Use the values stored in the session from the previous SetEC
         * call
         * '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        String nvpstr = "&TOKEN=" + token + "&PAYERID=" + payerID
                + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" + paymentType + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT="
                + finalPaymentAmount;

        nvpstr = nvpstr + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" + currencyCodeType + "&IPADDRESS="
                + serverName;

        nvpstr = nvpstr + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=" + item.get("name")
                + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=" + item.get("amt")
                + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=" + item.get("qty")
                + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital";

        /*
         * Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment If an error occured, show
         * the resulting errors
         */
        HashMap nvp = httpcall("DoExpressCheckoutPayment", nvpstr);
        String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();
        if (strAck != null
                && (strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success") || strAck
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("SuccessWithWarning"))) {
            return nvp;
        }
        return null;

    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     * httpcall: Function to perform the API call to PayPal using API signature @
     * methodName is name of API method. @ nvpStr is nvp string. returns a NVP
     * string containing the response from the server.
     *********************************************************************************/
    public HashMap httpcall(String methodName, String nvpStr) {

        String version = "2.3";
        String agent = "Mozilla/4.0";
        String respText = "";
        HashMap nvp = null; // lhuynh not used?

        // deformatNVP( nvpStr );
        String encodedData = "METHOD=" + methodName + "&VERSION=" + gv_Version
                + "&PWD=" + gv_APIPassword + "&USER=" + gv_APIUserName
                + "&SIGNATURE=" + gv_APISignature + nvpStr;

        try {
            URL postURL = new URL(gv_APIEndpoint);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) postURL
                    .openConnection();

            // Set connection parameters. We need to perform input and output,
            // so set both as true.
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Set the content type we are POSTing. We impersonate it as
            // encoded form data
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", agent);

            // conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", type );
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    String.valueOf(encodedData.length()));
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // get the output stream to POST to.
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes(encodedData);
            output.flush();
            output.close();

            // Read input from the input stream.
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (rc != -1) {
                BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                String _line = null;
                while (((_line = is.readLine()) != null)) {
                    respText = respText + _line;
                }
                nvp = deformatNVP(respText);
            }
            return nvp;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle the error here
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     * deformatNVP: Function to break the NVP string into a HashMap pPayLoad is
     * the NVP string. returns a HashMap object containing all the name value
     * pairs of the string.
     *********************************************************************************/
    public HashMap deformatNVP(String pPayload) {
        HashMap nvp = new HashMap();
        StringTokenizer stTok = new StringTokenizer(pPayload, "&");
        while (stTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            StringTokenizer stInternalTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
                    stTok.nextToken(), "=");
            if (stInternalTokenizer.countTokens() == 2) {
                String key = URLDecoder.decode(stInternalTokenizer.nextToken());
                String value = URLDecoder.decode(stInternalTokenizer
                        .nextToken());
                nvp.put(key.toUpperCase(), value);
            }
        }
        return nvp;
    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     * RedirectURL: Function to redirect the user to the PayPal site token is
     * the parameter that was returned by PayPal returns a HashMap object
     * containing all the name value pairs of the string.
     *********************************************************************************/
    public void RedirectURL(HttpServletResponse response, String token) {
        String payPalURL = PAYPAL_URL + token;

        // response.sendRedirect( payPalURL );
        response.setStatus(302);
        response.setHeader("Location", payPalURL);
        response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
    }

    // end class
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us which one is the line 72 in the `Checkout` class?

Comment: Is it this line: String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString(); - If so, either nvp is null or no value is found in the map for the "ACK" key. Can you debug to see?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, it was on line 36 

String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();

I have checked and nvp is null.

I have thought about the possibility that I have not set up my testing PayPal correctly, I don't see where I could have made a mistake but could that had been the cause of this weird error-like behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve my problem, however I was able to finish my project. I dropped all that code and tried sample project from:

https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java.

The project worked and so I just changed values, deleted all unnecessary code and rewrote the thing to work in my Tapestry5 app.

One of these days I will go back and figure out why the previously used code did not work, I'm thinking bad maven dependencies, but we will see.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following variables:

```
String returnURL = "localhost:8080/1/HelloWorld";
String cancelURL = "localhost:8080/1/HelloWorld";
```

To

```
String returnURL = "http://localhost:8080/1/HelloWorld";
String cancelURL = "http://localhost:8080/1/HelloWorld";
```

Issue: It is not able to validate Url as it does not have "http://"